# Azure Powershell set Cors allowed Origins

Tags: powershell, azure, continuous-integration, azure-web-app-service

I want to set the Cors allowedOrigins option via Powershell for an WebApp and was not able to get it working.

Can someone help how this is done?

Here are my scripts which have not worked

```
$Resource = Get-AzureRmResource -ResourceType Microsoft.Web/sites/config -ResourceGroupName "####" -ResourceName "####" -ApiVersion 2015-08-01
$Resource.Properties.cors =  @{allowedOrigins = "*"}
$Resource.Properties.cors.allowedOrigins = "*"
$Resource | Set-AzureRmResource -ApiVersion 2015-08-01 -Force
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution

the fix is

```
$Resource.Properties.cors =  @{allowedOrigins =  @("http://example.net")}
```

Answer (score 3):

The script provided in the blog [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/puneetgupta/2016/03/21/automating-webapps-hosted-in-azure-app-service-through-powershell-arm-way/#ModifyCorsSettingsForWebApp), can be utilized for this purpose:

```
$webAppName = "powershelldemowebapp"
$subscriptionId = "xxxx-xxxx-xxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxx"

Login-AzureRmAccount
Select-AzureRmSubscription -SubscriptionId $subscriptionId

$rgName = GetResourceGroupForWebApp $webAppName

$allowedOrigins = @()
$allowedOrigins += "*"
$allowedOrigins += "www.yourdomain.com"

$PropertiesObject = @{cors = @{allowedOrigins= $allowedOrigins}}

Set-AzureRmResource -PropertyObject $PropertiesObject -ResourceGroupName $rgName -ResourceType Microsoft.Web/sites/config -ResourceName $webAppName/web -ApiVersion 2015-08-01 -Force
```

Comment: For newer Azure Powershell, use `Set-AzResource` instead of `Set-AzureRmResource`